# Как дать доступ ssh (оба windows) для друга

Tags: ssh, cygwin, ssh-key, ssh-tunnel, openssh

Хочу дать доступ ssh для друга, у нас ОС windows, пробовал несолько способов в каждом разные проблемы из за которых не работает ssh, пробовал еще с cygwin вроде все успешно сделал стартанул sshd но друг не может ssh-ится.

Comment: фаервол, ошибки, etc?

Comment: Лично я давно и без каких-либо проблем использую дома Bitvise SSH Server. Настроил много лет назад, с тех пор все работает.